# Real life Example of multi variable calculus and vector integration in electrical engineering

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Is there any real life question or problem of electrical engineering which can be solved by multi variable calculus or vector calculus vector integration?

Comment: Um... pretty much every question in electricity and magnetism.

Comment: yes,can you give any example or any sort of numerical in the field of electrical engineering.?

Comment: You want to know the electric field around a pair of conductors -- say, a run of 14/2 cable, with a ground wire, typical in a home, with 120VAC between the conductors. You're interested in the magnitude of the field at a distance $d$ from the wire. Assume the wire runs straight for a length of about $4d$, to make the integral a little easier. Well, *that* exactly the kind of question you can answer by an integral of a vector-valued function (namely, the field due to a single charge).

Comment: I have been given the assignment to find out any real-world example of how multivariable calculus or vector integration has solved any numerical problem of electrical engineering.

Comment: do you any numerical regarding to this electrical engineering.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much every question in electricity and magnetism. Also, most questions in economics, many questions in finance, all of orbital mechanics (how do you think they get rocket ships to go where they're supposed to?).

I guess the short form is "Science." But also finance. Computer graphics (my own bias here). Most of engineering. Some topics in medicine. It's almost easier to answer "Is there a field of endeavor in which these ideas have *not* been applied?"

Comment: I have been given the assignment to find out any real-world example of how multivariable calculus or vector integration has solved any numerical problem of electrical engineering.

Comment: See my comment above.